# AngularJS function in table of objects

Tags: angularjs

I wrote this code in controller and It work good, but I know that I can do it without creating other function getSelect(). How to do the same in simpler method?

```
$scope.dosomething = function () {
        $scope.viewMode = viewMode;
        localStorage.setItem('viewMode', viewMode);
    };    

$scope.options = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: $translate.instant('FUN.OPTION1')
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: $translate.instant('FUN.OPTION2')
        }];

$scope.getSelect = function () {
        switch ($scope.options) {
            case '1': 
                $scope.bulkMode = 'addTags';
                $scope.hideSelect = true;
                break;
            case '2': 
                $scope.dosomething();
                break;
        }
};
```

Comment: Do you want the function to be available in your object? Do you have an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I added answer to this post

Answer (score 0):

Yes I want add functions in objects as object and use it in ng-change like ng-change="select.options.func()" or similar

This is actual view of this contoller

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="Select" ng-change="getSelect()">
    <option ng-repeat="el in Options" value="{{el.id}}">{{el.name}} </option>
</select>
```